# crystal reports .dll file for visual studio

Tags: c#, .net, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010, crystal-reports-xi

I'm working on crystal reports in my .net WPF application using 2013 visual studio.

I searched for the  the .dll file, I tried but couldn't find this:

"CrystalDecisions.Enterprise.Viewing.ReportSource.dll"

Comment: Which version you have installed for Crystal Report?

Comment: Look for Crystal Reports runtime. Be aware of your version.